# Marionette 2.2 how to hear the trigger event?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette

It was worked well with previous version of `marionette`. Now I updated to 2.2 newer version. But I am not able to hear my trigger now.

i understand it is updated and changed the approach. any one guide me to get the new approach please?

my trigger in itemView :

```
List.Contact = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        tagName : "tr",
        events: {
            "click": "highlightName"
        },

        triggers : {
            "click button.js-delete" : "contact:delete" // i trigger delete from here
        },
        template : "#contact-list-item",
        highlightName: function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            this.$el.toggleClass("warning");
        },
        remove : function () {
            var self = this;
            this.$el.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                Marionette.ItemView.prototype.remove.call(self);
            });
        }
    });
```

Here is i am trying to hear my trigger: (controller)

```
List.Controller = {
        listContacts : function () {
            var contacts = ContactManager.request("contact:entities");

            var contactsListView = new List.Contacts({
                collection : contacts
            });

            contactsListView.on("itemview:contact:delete", function (childView, Model) {
                console.log("i am hearing!"); //not working at all...
                contacts.remove(model); //is the way is wrong?
            });

            ContactManager.mainRegion.show(contactsListView);
        }
    }
```

Both are nested with separate modules. please help me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated `itemview` - in to `childview` - it's works fine.

```
List.Controller = {
        listContacts : function () {
            var contacts = ContactManager.request("contact:entities");

            var contactsListView = new List.Contacts({
                collection : contacts
            });

            contactsListView.on("childview:contact:delete", function (childView, Model) {
                console.log("i am hearing!"); //not working at all...
                contacts.remove(model); //is the way is wrong?
            });

            ContactManager.mainRegion.show(contactsListView);
        }
    }
```

Comment: the marionette wiki contains a brief guide to all the major breaking changes when moving from 1.X to 2.X http://stackoverflow.com/tags/marionette/info